# How to set a custom port for RMI regisrty?

Tags: java, rmi

In my RMI program I want to set up my RMI registry on the port 8080, but when I do it, I get an exception.

Here is my server code

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(8080);
            MathServerImpl mathServer = new MathServerImpl();
            Naming.rebind("MathServer", mathServer);
            System.out.println("Math Server has started and is running");
        } catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code works properly for the port 1099, which is it's default port as far as I know, but for this case it gives me a java.net.ConnectException, and here is the log.

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.100.25.173; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at server.Server.main(Server.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a registry on port 8080 but then attempting to `rebind` your object in the default registry on port 1099. You need to either:

- pass a full URL to `Naming.rebind` including the port number, i.e. `//localhost:8080/MathServer` or
- save a reference to the `Registry` object returned by `LocateRegistry.createRegistry` and bind the object using that registry's instance methods rather than the static methods of `Naming`

Similarly, you will need to use the full `//localhost:8080/MathServer` URL form in your clients when they `lookup` the object, to make sure they're talking to the right registry.

Comment: Could you please tell also how should I define my clients lookup for that two cases? Both solutions started the server properly, but the client now does not connect

Comment: Just forgot to set the port number in the client side, that's it, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
Naming.rebind("MathServer", mathServer);
```

Change that to

```
Naming.rebind("//localhost:8080/MathServer", mathServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are linux Ubuntu user then while starting RMI registry use command

rmiregistry 8080 &

For Windows

start rmiregistry 8080

Comment: I am a mac user, but I want to do it in the code, not from the terminal.